# WordPress image uploads on IIS

Tags: php, wordpress, iis

I have **WordPress v4.3.1** installed on **IIS 8** on **Windows Server 2012 R2**.

Everything seems to work fine except for image uploads, and even they work sometimes! It is strange. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't!

I have edited my `php.ini` file and told PHP where to store temp files, and I ensured that `IUSR` has full control of that PHP temp directory.

Also did the same thing on my `wp-content` folder, so `IUSR` has full control on that too.

Here is how things look. I upload some images (.e.g mac and keyboard) to my Media Library, all seems fine as below:

[image: media library]

But when I click the image, I see this:

[image: missing image]

On the front end, it also is missing. Why is this happening!

Comment: I've had problems (not on IIS, but it may be related) with file names with accented characters.  Is there anything unusual about the file names?

Comment: They have a hyphen `-` in them?

Comment: That should be ok, assuming it's not some other character masquerading as a hyphen.  If you FTP onto the server and look in your uploads directory, is the file name unchanged (if it's unchanged, this probably isn't the problem)?  Alternatively, does it work if you rename the file and remove the hyphen and reupload?

Comment: Just tried uploading images with only alphabetical names, but still got the same issue. I looked at the files on the server, the name has stayed the same, but there is another with the same name but smaller. So if I upload `jamesbrown.jpg`, then on the server `jamesbrown.jpg` and `jamesbrown-94x70.jpg` exist.

Comment: Ok, not the problem I've seen then.  The other file names are normal - WordPress will create various different sizes based on your media settings (those probably include the ones that look ok in the media library).  Is the original file on the server (`jamesbrown.jpg`) the same size as the one you uploaded?  What browser are you using?  Any chance the original file is CMYK, not RGB?  Those don't display correctly on all browsers

Comment: Just checked photo size, it is the same on the server as well. As for the images, they are RGB, I checked that too :(